# Como puedo obtener el contexto de un activity con espresso?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

Estoy realizando pruebas de UI Tengo 2 activitys

> activityUno.java y activityDos.java

Yo se que para obtener el contexto de la activtyUno.java utilizo el siguiente metodo:

```
private Context contextActivityUno;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        activityUno.class);

context = mActivityRule.getActivity();
```

pero cuando hago la transición a la activityDos.java quiero obtener tambien el contexto de esta activity pero no se como realizarlo por que en la activityDos.java tengo un recycler view que necesito bindiar

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.our_recycler_view);
```

Comment: ¿Deseas acceder a recursos de la activityDos ?

Comment: Si quiero acceder a los recursos de la actividad a la que he pasado

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el contexto de la activity es precisamente como lo realizas:

```
Activity activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
```

pero si vas a realizar una transición hacia otra Activity y quieres obtener el contexto, en este caso puedes usar el contexto de la aplicación mediante [getTargetContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html#getTargetContext())

```
 Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
```

Comment: Pero como hago para obtener el de la activity a la que pasó, para poder usar el findViewById(); ?